# Remove the coordinates in the location column

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geopy

Would like to have the coordinates in their own respective columns.

This is my `df["Boroughs"]`

```
0            Beaches-East York
1                    Davenport
2            Eglinton-Lawrence
3             Etobicoke Centre
4              Etobicoke North
5     Humber River-Black Creek
6           Parkdale-High Park
7        Scarborough-Agincourt
8       Scarborough-Rouge Park
9             Toronto-Danforth
10                  Willowdale
11                 York Centre
Name: Boroughs, dtype: object
```

**My steps:**

```
dfB = []
city = 'Toronto, Canada'
boroughs  = df["Boroughs"]
for borough in boroughs:
  try:
    address = borough + ', ' + city
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foursquare_agent")
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    lat = location.latitude
    lng = location.longitude
    dfB.append([location, lat, lng])
  except Exception as e:
    print(address, lat, lng)

dfB = pd.DataFrame(dfB, columns=["location", "lat", "lng"])
dfB
```

**The Output:** 
How can I remove the extra info and the coordinates from the location column?

```
    location    lat lng
0   (Beaches—East York, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.6814698, -79.3060214)) 43.681470   -79.306021
1   (Davenport, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.6715614, -79.4482927)) 43.671561   -79.448293
2   (Eglinton—Lawrence, North York, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.7192647, -79.429765))   43.719265   -79.429765
3   (Etobicoke Centre, Etobicoke, Toronto, Ontario, Canada, (43.6798327, -79.5389927))  43.679833   -79.538993
4   (Etobicoke North, Etobicoke, Toronto, Ontario, Canada, (43.7410925, -79.5892249))   43.741093   -79.589225
5   (Humber River—Black Creek, North York, Toronto, Ontario, Canada, (43.7337368, -79.5382285)) 43.733737   -79.538229
6   (Parkdale—High Park, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.6499649, -79.473014)) 43.649965   -79.473014
7   (Scarborough—Agincourt, Scarborough, Toronto, Ontario, Canada, (43.797221, -79.3083901035784))  43.797221   -79.308390
8   (Scarborough—Rouge Park, Scarborough, Toronto, Ontario, Canada, (43.80292335, -79.175434369733))    43.802923   -79.175434
9   (Toronto—Danforth, Old Toronto, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.6789439, -79.3448597))  43.678944   -79.344860
10  (Willowdale, North York, Toronto, Ontario, Canada, (43.7753558, -79.4166859823926)) 43.775356   -79.416686
11  (York Centre, North York, Toronto, Golden Horseshoe, Ontario, Canada, (43.750241, -79.463352))  43.750241   -79.463352
```

**Expected Output:**

```
    location             lat         lng
0   Beaches—East York   43.681470   -79.306021
1   Davenport           43.671561   -79.448293
2   Eglinton—Lawrence  43.719265    -79.429765
3   Etobicoke Centre.  43.679833    -79.538993
.....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
Assuming location column has data in `tuples` in each row.

```
dfB.location=dfB.location.apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all values in one column because you are appending a list to a list, while you want your final output to be a dataframe.

Try:

```
dfB = pd.DataFrame()
city = 'Toronto, Canada'
boroughs  = df["Boroughs"]
for borough in boroughs:
  try:
    address = borough + ', ' + city
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foursquare_agent")
    location = geolocator.geocode(address)
    lat = location.latitude
    lng = location.longitude
    dfB = dfB.append([[location, lat, lng]])
  except Exception as e:
    print(address, lat, lng)

dfB.columns = ["location", "lat", "lng"]
dfB
```

Comment: I get the same result with this.

Comment: Because, location variable itself contain all data including lat, long. and this variable is going into append function.